# how to subscribe an item from localstorage in angular 2 and when changed, get value

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an application with angular 2, and my problem is how to subscribe an item from local storage... I know I must use a service, only access LocalStorage through this service from everywhere, but I don't know how this can be done.

Answer (score 28):

For a basic Idea this is how it can be done.

Just need to write the correct Import paths accotding to your configuration

---

**Write a global service:**

```ts
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';   

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class GlobalService {
 itemValue = new BehaviorSubject(this.theItem);

 set theItem(value) {
   this.itemValue.next(value); // this will make sure to tell every subscriber about the change.
   localStorage.setItem('theItem', value);
 }

 get theItem() {
   return localStorage.getItem('theItem');
 }
}
```

**Usage:**

- Any change here

```ts
@Component({})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private globalSrv: GlobalService){}

  someEvent() {
    this.globalSrv.theItem = 'someValue'; // this change will broadcast to every subscriber like below component
  }
}
```

- Will Reflect Here

```ts
@Component({})
export class AnotherComponent {
  constructor(private globalSrv: GlobalService){
    
      globalSrv.itemValue.subscribe((nextValue) => {
         alert(nextValue);  // this will happen on every change
      })
  
  }
}
```

Comment: i have question...when need i use from behaviorsubject?why you use use from Subject?

Comment: I assumed that you don't have a  default value, to use `BehaviorSubject` you need to define a Default value, just that.

Comment: can you please explain briefly, where i import GlobalService? please post stackblitz, iam struggle Bootstrap this Service:

Comment: I thought the exact same thing, however the issue with this approach is that you will not be notified when the user updates localStorage.

Comment: "provideIn" should be "providedIn" - typo in above post, just in case someone is confused.

Comment: this is hack not listening to localstorage technically. If I go and manually change localsotrage items, this won't work obviously.